# Infomation about the Still from M.A.S.H

Tags: techniques

i was wondering if anyone knows of any recreations of Hawkeyes Still for the TV show MASH?

or really even just some basic infomation about similar Still setups would be amazing.
at this point its more for interests sake then a plan to build my own.

Thanks!

p.s im stuggling to think of what to tag this, so please feel free to add tags you think will fit!

Comment: This site is for homebrewing, not distilling.